# How to change flipping rate of HubTile control for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I need to change a flipping rate for *HubTitle* control that I use in my *Windows Phone 8* application. Please provide any guidance how to modify source code of HubTitle control in order to change flipping rate.

Comment: Did you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with published control. Since it is a opensource code, you can change the flip rate in the HubTile control code (class name: Microsoft.Phone.Controls.HubTileService.cs).

You have to fork the code to make these changes, flip side is you can't get the new regular updates.